# send value to php file using ajax to update database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am new at this, and am not quite sure what I'm doing, I'm learning as I go ahead.

I have assigned a variable to store the value of rowID. Now I want to send that rowID value to a php file so I can use it in a where clause.

This is my ajax part.

```
                $.ajax(
            {
              type: "POST",
              url: "completed.php",
              data: { complete: "$rowID" }
            })
            .done(function( msg ) 
            {
                alert( "Data Saved" + msg );
            });
```

I am unsure of what the next step it. Could anyone help me out please? What do I need to do in order to use that value in a query.

This is part of the query in the completed.php file. (I have the connection and all before it)

```
$query = "UPDATE tbl_todo SET completed=1 WHERE id= $rowID ";
```

Comment: what is the `"$rowID"` in your ajax data? Where does it come from?

Comment: Where is the rowId coming from. It looks like it's coming from the client side.

Comment: And for the love of god don't stick that $rowID in that query raw. You prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

You can't use PHP variables in your script like that.
You will have to use PHP to echo it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rowId = "<?php echo $rowID; ?>";
</script>
```

And in your PHP (completed.php) you will have to refer to it as 'complete', that is the name you are using when sending it.